# Replace URL using JS in menu only inside li with certain class on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a menu like this on my WordPress site:

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="clearfix"><li id="menu-item-397" class="menu-item-397"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/o-nas/">About us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1001" class="menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-dropdown menu-item-1001"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/oferta/">OFFER</a>
<ul class="nav-dropdown">
    <li id="menu-item-454" class="not_on_mobile menu-item-has-children has-dropdown menu-item-454"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/ginekolog-poznan-suchy-las/">PROBLEM</a>
    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li id="menu-item-1569" class="menu-item-1569"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/prowadzenie-ciazy-poznan/">Test</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1572" class="menu-item-1572"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/usg-ciazy-3d-4d-poznan/">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-1063" class="not_on_mobile menu-item-has-children has-dropdown menu-item-1063"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/ginekologia-estetyczna-poznan/">PROBLEM</a>
    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li id="menu-item-1242" class="menu-item-1242"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/labioplastyka-laserowa-poznan/">Test</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1243" class="menu-item-1243"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/wysilkowe-nietrzymanie-moczu-leczenie-laserem-poznan/">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-508" class="not_on_mobile menu-item-has-children has-dropdown menu-item-508"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/stomatologia-suchy-las-dentystyka/">PROBLEM</a>
    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li id="menu-item-670" class="menu-item-670"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/chirurg-stomatolog-poznan/">Test</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1133" class="menu-item-1133"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/stomatolog-dzieciecy-suchy-las/">Test</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1427" class="menu-item-1427"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/wybielanie-zebow-lampa-nakladkowe-poznan/">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-673" class="menu-item-673"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/ortodonta-suchy-las/">Ortodoncja</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-443" class="not_on_mobile menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-dropdown menu-item-443"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/radiolog-poznan/">PROBLEM</a>
    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
        <li id="menu-item-1820" class="menu-item-1820"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/usg-jamy-brzusznej/">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-1160" class="menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1160"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/endokrynolog-poznan/">Test</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-741" class="menu-item-741"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/medycyna-estetyczna-suchy-las/">Test</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-523" class="menu-item-523"><a href="https://www.my_url.com/cennik-uslug/">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that on mobile, when I click on elements that I called PROBLEM, the URL is triggered and it expands another level of menu but in the same time enters an url I just clicked.
I thought that the fix for this could be to replace this PROBLEM URL's by a link like #menu_on_mobile
All of those PROBLEM url's are the first 'a' items in li which has a 'not_on_mobile' class.

I tried to do it like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".not_on_mobile a:first-child").forEach(a => a.setAttribute('href', '#menu_on_mobile'));
```

But the problem is that it replaces URL in all 'a' element in not_on_mobile class.

How to edit it to replace only the first element in 'li' and work only on mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to select the items this way `.not_on_mobile>a`. In this way, only the first elements will be selected without taking all the children's elements inside.
I hope I understood the task correctly

```
document.querySelectorAll(".not_on_mobile>a").forEach(a => a.setAttribute('href', '#menu_on_mobile'));
```

Comment: Thanks! My explanation wasn't the best. So now it changes all URLs inside the ul which is inside li that has the not_on_mobile. 
The goal is to do the opposite. 
Not edit those URLs inside ul. Edit just the first a element after not_on_mobile class.
Edit only URLs that have 'PROBLEM' inside in the above's case

Comment: @Luk_9900, I edit my post. Please try again!